# Recommendation for a WordPress Calendar Plugin with Recurring Events?

Tags: events

I'm building a base WordPress theme that will cater mainly to an events calendar plugin (yet to be decided.) I'm curious what WordPress users consider to be the best solution in terms of stability and usability?

I should note that **recurring events are a must-have feature** but that's just personal preference. This is a free GPL project that will be publically available as a basic greyscale starting point for other theme builders.

I'd like to know first though, **which plugin do seasoned WordPress developers use**?

Answer (score 3):

You may wish to consider [Event Organiser](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/event-organiser/) as well (*disclaimer: I'm the developer*). It's completely free, supports reoccurring events and shortcodes & widgets for displaying them in lists and calendars.

(I realise this is an old question, but it may be useful to others)

Answer (score 1):

The only decent WP events plugin I've found is the [Events Calendar](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/the-events-calendar/). It's a good plugin, but unfortunately it doesn't have recurring events. Every other plugin I've used has been horrible.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have specific experience with a calendar plugin yet but there was a [**hugely useful discussion on LinkedIn in the WordPress Group**](http://www.linkedin.com/groupAnswers?viewQuestionAndAnswers=&discussionID=17984356&gid=154024) about calendar/event plugins with many people offering many suggestions.

I'd highly recommend you join the group on LinkedIn if you are not already a member (it's free to join it) so you can check out that thread:

- LinkedIn Group Discussion: [**Listed Event or Calendar Plugin for WordPress?**](http://www.linkedin.com/groupAnswers?viewQuestionAndAnswers=&discussionID=17984356&gid=154024)

There is also the EventPress plugin developed this year as part of Google Summer of Code; expect that it will get a lot of support from the core community because of its origin:

- [**EventPress from GSOC 2010**](http://gsoc2010.wordpress.com/2010/08/16/eventpress/)

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I was trying to find a suitable plugin as well, but ended up using Google Calendar with some integration to WordPress.  You can have the calendar embedded on the page, or list events with an RSS feed or via iCal files/URLs.

Not always a viable alternative, but might get your problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can try out Event Espresso -> [Event Espresso](http://eventespresso.com/)

Answer (score 0):

[Timely](http://time.ly/pricing/) makes a pretty awesome calendar plugin and includes a whole lot of options in its Free plan.

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged. If something happens to that link the answer becomes useless. Please try to make your answer here stand alone.